# Putting a value from a method into a data frame

Tags: python, methods

```
def number():
    for i in dataframe:
        if i > 10:
            print('large')
        elif i <= 10:
            print('small')                 
number()
small
small
large
small
```

Is there any possible way you can incorporate those values, specifically ones that you get from a method, such as the example above into a DF such as a pandas data frame?

Comment: Instead of `print`ing the values search for how to insert values in a `DataFrame`

Comment: let us know what you came up with when you searched for adding values to dataframe

Comment: is this a `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: yes this is a pandas data frame. I should probably rephrase. I know how to put the values, such as small and large into a DF, but I was wondering if there is anyway to take the values that were given by the method, and directly transfer them into a DF without manually putting them in.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to bear in mind with *pandas* is that, in many situations, it expects vector-valued operators and functions. The answer is to use *numpy*

This seems to do what you want. Notice that *where* is, roughly speaking, the vector-valued equivalent of your function.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1,9,10,11,15])
>>> B = len(A)*[2]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B})
>>> df
    A  B
0   1  2
1   9  2
2  10  2
3  11  2
4  15  2
>>> df.assign(C=np.where(A>10,len(A)*['large'],len(A)*['small']))
    A  B      C
0   1  2  small
1   9  2  small
2  10  2  small
3  11  2  large
4  15  2  large
```

Comment: This definitely works. So with this, your basically creating the function within the pandas data frame? Also what is the logic for you putting the B variable?